# Algorithm to create X number of dates

Tags: java, algorithm, date, calendar, yearmonth

Currently I have a list of Strings that represent a date in a yyyyMM format, something like this:

- 202008
- 202009
- 202010

I need to create x number of entries in this list with each entry increasing the month by one, so if I were to create 3 new entries they would look like this:

- 202011
- 202012
- 202101

Currently my idea is to create a method to pick the latest date, parse the String to separate month and year, increase the month value by 1 if it is < 12 otherwise set it to 1 and increase the year instead.
Then I would add that value to a list and set it as the most recent, repeating x number of times.

What I want to know is if there is a more elegant solution that I could use, maybe using an existing date library (I'm using Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) And [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

I recommend you do it using these [modern date-time classes](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) as shown below:

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        List<String> list = getYearMonths("202011", 3);
        System.out.println(list);

        // Bonus: Print each entry of the obtained list, in a new line
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static List<String> getYearMonths(String startWith, int n) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // Define Formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM");

        // Parse the year-month string using the defined formatter
        YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(startWith, formatter);

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            list.add(ym.format(formatter));
            ym = ym.plusMonths(1);// Increase YearMonth by one month
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[202011, 202012, 202101]
202011
202012
202101
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

### Use proper date-time objects: YearMonth

Don’t store your dates as strings in your list. Just as you use `int` for numbers and `boolean` for Boolean values (I hope!), use proper date-time objects for dates and times. For your use case the `YearMonth` class is appropriate.

And just as it’s easy to format an `int` into a format with or without thousand separators and a `boolean` into *yes* or *no*, for example, formatting your `YearMonth` objects into strings is trivial. So do that when you need a string, not before.

A method for extending such a list of `YearMonth` objects would be:

```
public static void extendDateList(List<YearMonth> dates, int numberOfNewDates) {
    if (dates.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty; don’t know where to pick up");
        // Or may start from some fixed date or current month
    } else {
        YearMonth current = Collections.max(dates);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNewDates; i++) {
            current = current.plusMonths(1);
            dates.add(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    List<YearMonth> dates = new ArrayList<YearMonth>(List.of(
            YearMonth.of(2020, Month.AUGUST), 
            YearMonth.of(2020, Month.SEPTEMBER),
            YearMonth.of(2020, Month.OCTOBER)));
    
    extendDateList(dates, 3);
    
    System.out.println(dates);
```

Output is:

> [2020-08, 2020-09, 2020-10, 2020-11, 2020-12, 2021-01]

### Formatting into strings

I promised you you could easily have your strings. I would suggest using the format with a hyphen printed above for two reasons: (1) it’s more readable, and (2) it’s ISO 8601 format, the international standard. In any case, to demonstrate that you can have it just the way you want, I am using a formatter to produce the hyphen-less format that you used:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter YEAR_MONTH_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM");
```

Now converting to a list of strings is a one-liner (if your editor window is wide enough):

```
    List<String> datesAsStrings = dates.stream()
            .map(YEAR_MONTH_FORMATTER::format)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(datesAsStrings);
```

> [202008, 202009, 202010, 202011, 202012, 202101]

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just dealing with strings you could just create a method to produce the string dates for you and return all those string dates in a String Array, like this:

```
public static String[] addMonthsToDateString(String startDate, int monthsToAdd) {
    // Break the string date down to integers Year and month.
    int year = Integer.valueOf(startDate.substring(0, 4));
    int month = Integer.valueOf(startDate.substring(4));
    // Calculate the number of iterations we need.
    int loopCount = ((month + monthsToAdd) - month);
    // Declare and initialize the String Array we will return.
    String[] stringDates = new String[loopCount];
    
    // Generate the required Date Strings
    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
        stringDates[i] = new StringBuilder("").append(year)
                         .append(String.format("%02d", month)).toString();
        month++;
        if (month == 13) {
            year++;
            month = 1;
        }
    }
    return stringDates;
}
```

To use this method you would need to supply a string start date ("202008") and the integer number of months you want to list (24):

```
// Get the desired list of string dates:
String[] desiredDates = addMonthsToDateString("202008", 24);

// Display the string dates produced into the Console Window:
for (String strg : desiredDates) {
    System.out.println(strg);
}
```

The Console Window will display:

```
202008
202009
202010
202011
202012
202101
202102
202103
202104
202105
202106
202107
202108
202109
202110
202111
202112
202201
202202
202203
202204
202205
202206
202207
```